# Error while converting float datatype column to double

Tags: c#

Below code gives error: **Specified cast is not valid.**

```
protected void gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
           DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
           **double Yellow = Convert.ToDouble(row.Field<float?>("Yellow"));**
        }
    }
```

While below code works for me. But I'm unable to handle `NULL` values in below code

```
double Yellow = Convert.ToDouble(((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["Yellow"]);
```

Please help..

Comment: What is the type of Field `Yellow` , it may be `double?`

Comment: datatype of `Yellow`  is float

Comment: then try `float` instead of `float?`

Comment: I want to handle database `NULL` values in `Yellow` column & hence have used `float?`. Even then, if I remove `?`, it gives me same error: **Specified cast is not valid.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to break them into multiple lines to avoid breaking Law of Demeter. It would make it easier to read.

```
var dataRowView = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
DataRow row = dataRowView.Row;
var result = ( row["Yellow"] as double? ) ?? 0.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
double? Yellow = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["Yellow"] != null ? Convert.ToDouble(((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["Yellow"]) : (double?)null;
```

Comment: I'm not even able to compile this. **Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'double' and '<null>'**

Comment: :( Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

Comment: maybe it is not a float? try cas it to string & after that parse as double : double? Yellow = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["Yellow"] != null ? double.Parse((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["Yellow"].ToString()) : (double?)null;

Comment: it is float.. I've access to DB and i've cross checked.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I had to use `System.DBNull.Value` check

```
if (((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["Yellow"] != System.DBNull.Value)
            {
               double? Yellow =
                    (double?)Convert.ToDouble(((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["Yellow"]);
            }
```